# LINQ Query Decimal Field to Constant Value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a stack of different colored pick-up sticks that I want to remove duplicates and sort by color and by shortest to longest in each color.

Here's my partial code:

```
StickStack stickstack = new StickStack();
List<Stick> noDupeSticks = stickstack.Pile
    .GroupBy(st => new { st.LengthInCm, st.ColorBlue, st.ColorGreen, st.ColorRed })
    .Select(st => st.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
var blueSticks = noDupeSticks
    .OrderBy(s => s.LengthInCm)
    .Where(s => s.LengthInCm >= 5.0m && s.LengthInCm <= 20.0m && s.ColorBlue >= s.ColorGreen && s.ColorBlue >= s.ColorRed)
    .Select(s => new Stick(s.LengthInCm, s.ColorRed, s.ColorGreen, s.ColorBlue));
var greenSticks = noDupeSticks
    .OrderBy(s => s.LengthInCm)
    .Where(s => s.LengthInCm >= 5.0m && s.LengthInCm <= 20.0m && s.ColorGreen >= s.ColorBlue && s.ColorGreen >= s.ColorRed)
    .Select(s => new Stick((decimal)s.LengthInCm, s.ColorRed, s.ColorGreen, s.ColorBlue));
SortByColorResult result = new SortByColorResult();
result.Blues = blueSticks.ToList();
result.Greens = greenSticks.ToList();
```

Instantiating StickStack creates a `List<Stick>` Pile of sticks.

Unfortunately, somewhere in all this, the LengthInCm values (which should range from 5.0m to 20.0m) all come out as 5.

Anybody have any idea what's wrong here?

EDIT In response to comments:
Here's the Stick class:

```
    public class Stick
{
    public decimal LengthInCm { get; private set; }
    public int ColorRed { get; private set; }
    public int ColorGreen { get; private set; }
    public int ColorBlue { get; private set; }

    public Stick(
        decimal lengthInCm,
        int colorRed,
        int colorGreen,
        int colorBlue)
    {
        LengthInCm = lengthInCm;
        ColorRed = colorRed;
        ColorGreen = colorGreen;
        ColorBlue = colorBlue;
    }
}
```

As you can see, LengthInCm is a decimal; the rest of the fields are int. Also, someone in the comments asked why my sorter routine explicitly cast length values as decimal. This is just one of the many things I tried to make LengthInCm appear as a decimal with a value other than 5.

Some sample Sticks are:

```
        stick1 = new Stick(10.00m, 256, 128, 50);
        stick2 = new Stick(10.00m, 256, 128, 50);
        stick3 = new Stick(20.00m, 128, 50, 256);
```

As I mentioned previously instantiating Stickstack, creates a Pile (List) of somewhere between 2 million and 5 million records.

The LengthInCm for each record is a random decimal between 5.0 and 20.0.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: To add Pile creation code:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            _pile.Add(
                new Straw(
                    generator.Next(LENGTH_MIN, LENGTH_MAX) / (decimal)10,
                    generator.Next(COLOR_MIN, COLOR_MAX),
                    generator.Next(COLOR_MIN, COLOR_MAX),
                    generator.Next(COLOR_MIN, COLOR_MAX)
                ));
        }
```

Also, so you'll know what the constants are:

```
    private const int PILE_SIZE_MIN = 2000000;
    private const int PILE_SIZE_MAX = 3000000;
    private const int COLOR_MIN = 0;
    private const int COLOR_MAX = 256;
    private const int LENGTH_MIN = 50;
    private const int LENGTH_MAX = 200;
```

And, because somebody will ask, here's the output after the first LINQ statement (list with dupes removed).
[image]

And some more just to prove that the LengthInCm does change:
 [image]

Finally, here's a sample of the blue stick list:
[image]
[image]

Don't know what else to tell you. The query that creates noDupeSticks clearly has increasing decimal values for LengthInCm, but the query that creates the blue subset, only returns 5 for LengthInCm.

Thanks.

Comment: I highly doubt we'd be able to figure this out without seeing what the input data looks like; if you post sample input and expected output, then we can try to help figure out why it doesn't match.

Comment: You should provide definitions of all the types used in your example...

Comment: Why are you explicitly casting the length as decimal here: `var greenSticks = noDupeSticks
    .OrderBy(s => s.LengthInCm)
    .Where(s => s.LengthInCm >= 5.0m && s.LengthInCm <= 20.0m && s.ColorGreen >= s.ColorBlue && s.ColorGreen >= s.ColorRed)
    .Select(s => new Stick((decimal)s.LengthInCm, s.ColorRed, s.ColorGreen, s.ColorBlue));` ? What is the type of Stick.LengthInCm?

Comment: Just trying to make the decimal LengthInCm appear as the decimal and actual value that it's supposed to be.

Comment: Can we see how you're generating your sticks? I'm not seeing anything here yet that would eliminate sticks longer than 5. My guess is that your input isn't what you think it is or that the way you're viewing the output only makes it _appear_ like nothing is > 5.

Comment: You didn't add the sticks to stickstack.  Use following :  List<Stick> stickstack = new List<Stick>();
stickstack.Add(stick1); stickstack.Add(stick2); stickstack.Add(stick3);

Comment: I did add the sticks a little later in the code, before the LINQ statements.

Comment: This is most likely a problem with your StickStack class's constructor. You are most probably not generating the random numbers correctly. I created a working sample but lost the data due to an accident so I know it works if done with the proper random number generation methods.

Comment: I copied your code with some modification, it does work flawlessly. I wonder how you define `SortByColorResult` class

Comment: you have 2 million records and it is ordered, you might just have 300 items with length = 5. Try look beyond, for example the 1.5 million'th item, you should be able to see difference.